# Retrieving value from a method

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a value from a method using getters and setters, but cannot get it to return anything besides 0. Here is my current code:

```
int goodRow;

    int boardStatus[][] = { 
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    };

    public void placePiece(int column) {
        boolean goodInput = false;
        while(!goodInput) {
            for(int x = 5; x >= 0; x--) {
                if(boardStatus[x][column] == 0) {

                    setRow(x);

                    boardStatus[x][column] = 1;
                    goodInput = true;
                    break;

                }else if(boardStatus[0][x] == 1) {
                    goodInput = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return goodRow;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        goodRow = row;
    }
```

My goal is to be able to call getRow() and retrieve the x value that was accepted in the method. Inside my `placePiece()` method, I use my `setRow()` method to get the x value, but my strategy hasn't worked so far. How can I get the x value from my method so that I can use it elsewhere in my program?

-----EDIT-----

Here is my full code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    moveMaker mover = new moveMaker();
    clickDetector click = new clickDetector();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);

        for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
                g.fillOval(x*70 + 10, y*70 + 10, 50, 50);
            }
        }       
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 430, 500, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("CONNECT FOUR", 250, 450);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        click.paintPiece(g);
    }

    public void setUpGUI() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        clickDetector click = new clickDetector();

        mainFrame.addMouseListener(click);
        mainFrame.addMouseListener(this);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(this);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {   
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {     
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setUpGUI();

    }

}
```

--

```
public class moveMaker {

    int goodRow;

    int boardStatus[][] = { 
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    };

    public void placePiece(int column) {
        boolean goodInput = false;
        while(!goodInput) {
            for(int x = 5; x >= 0; x--) {
                if(boardStatus[x][column] == 0) {

                    setRow(x);

                    boardStatus[x][column] = 1;
                    goodInput = true;
                    break;

                }else if(boardStatus[0][x] == 1) {  
                    setRow(x);
                    goodInput = true;
                    break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println(x + " is taken.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return goodRow;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        goodRow = row;
    }

}
```

--

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class clickDetector implements MouseListener {

    moveMaker mover = new moveMaker();

    int mouseX = 0;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int xLocation = (e.getX() + 10)/70;
        mover.placePiece(xLocation);
        setMouseX(xLocation);
        System.out.println("Place piece at " + mouseX + ", " + mover.getRow() + ".");

    }

    public void paintPiece(Graphics g) {
        int x = (getMouseX()+10)/70;
        int y = (mover.getRow()+10)/70;
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
    }

    public int getMouseX() {
        return mouseX;
    }

    public void setMouseX(int x) {
        mouseX = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you cannot get your getter to return anything but zero, this might be an indication that your goodRow variable is never set to a value (as the default value is zero). Are you sure you are calling setRow before calling getRow?

Comment: @jyr Yes, I set breakpoints at setRow(x) and getRow(x) in my other class and setRow(x) was hit first.

Comment: Can you show the code that is using this code?

Comment: @MoisheLipsker I've added my full code to my question.

Comment: Does each class have its own instance of moveMaker on purpose? Perhaps they should all share one instance as opposed to making separate instances can possibly be out of sync with each other.

Comment: I can't reproduce your 'error'. If you'd add a main method, create an instance of moveMaker class and invoke e.g. `instance.placePiece(0)` goodRow will set to 5 just fine (and as expected). You said something about breakpoints in your other class, but I'm not seeing them anywhere.

Comment: @jyr The breakpoints were just toggled on in Eclipse to test the two methods. Being able to call placePiece in my main method isn't the issue, I need to be able to user the `mouseX` variable from the clickDetector class and the `x` variable from the moveMaker class in my `paintPiece` method so that the piece are displayed on screen when the user makers a move.

Comment: @jyr I missed that, that math was only supposed to be on the x value. Although, when I print out click.getRow() in my paintPiece() method, it still has a value of 0 without the math being done on it.

Comment: I noticed. The problem is that your two MouseListeners are interfering with each other. It looks like the GUI one is overriding the clickListener one. I'm no expert on this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your mouseListener from the clickDetector class, and create a new method;

```
public void setUpVariables(int x) {
    int xLocation = (x + 10)/70;
    mover.placePiece(xLocation);
    setMouseX(xLocation);
    System.out.println("Place piece at " + mouseX + ", " + mover.getRow() + ".");
}
```

Now, in your GUI class, in the mouseClicked method, you can add

```
    click.setUpVariables(e.getX());
```

For correct painting, the paintPiece method needs to be adjusted a bit

```
public void paintPiece(Graphics g) {
    int x = (getMouseX())*70 + 10;
    int y = mover.getRow()*70 + 10;
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: This works! A few bugs I need to fix but its painting properly! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. This is a workaround though, I'm not fully understanding why the mouselisteners are interfering,  maybe someone will see this question and shed some light :).

Answer (score 0):

You have not invoked the `setRow(x)` within this block:

```
else if(boardStatus[0][x] == 1) {
    goodInput = true;
    break;
} else { //missing 
   ...
}
```

Also you are missing `else` block.

*Edited:*

Try debugging method `setRow()` and watch the param value.

Comment: I fixed this but it's still returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

I placed your code inside a class called Trial and added this main():

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Trial t = new Trial();
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        t.placePiece(k);
        System.out.println(k + ", " + t.getRow());
    }
}
```

The output was:

```
0, 5
1, 5
2, 5
3, 5
4, 5
```

This is the expected output: the method `placePiece(n)` only calls `setRow(n)` if the value of `boardStatus[5][n]` is 0 (which it always is) and ends the loop;
When you call `getRow()`the value will be 5, the row the loop was in when you called the setter!.
Looking at the logic of your while loop, it boils down to

```
while(true){
     setRow(5);
     break;
}
```

or more simply

```
public void placePiece(int column){
     setRow(5);
}
```

Comment: So in my code, what would be the best approach to getting the values of my variables to reach the methods?

Comment: I assume you are trying to call the placePiece(column) method to place a piece in a stack. If the stack is empty, it gets placed at the bottom, if not, it gets placed on top of the highest piece. Then it would be necessary to be sure your while loop did not end until it had found an empty slot - so do not call break until the test boardStatus[x][column] == 0 is true!. Lose the else clause.